# Remove In-memory kafka records receive from fetch in Springboot project

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a requirment, if i can remove in-memory kafka messages which was fetched as i have max-poll-records: 10. so the scenario is : while processing the record one by one, if my program encounter any error, i don't need to process any further left over records which stored in-memory.
Ex : i fetch 10 records at once as my max-poll-interval is 10. i processed 5 records successfully (committing manually) but during 6th records i encounter an error, now i have to remove all left over 5 records from in-memory. below is my listener code :

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.consumer.allTopicList}'.split(',')}", groupId = Constant.GROUP_ID)
public void consumeAllTopics(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic, String message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    switch (topic) {
        case Constant.toipc1:
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
                try {
                      //processing logic
                      acknowledgment.acknowledge();
                    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
```

i want to remove records through code. Please help me to understand if it is possible, and if so how can i achive this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "remove". If you mean "ignore" or "skip", you would need to to throw an exception and configure a custom error handler.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek-to-current).

> If an `ErrorHandler` implements `RemainingRecordsErrorHandler`, the error handler is provided with the failed record and any unprocessed records retrieved by the previous poll(). Those records are not passed to the listener after the handler exits.

There is no standard error handler to "skip" the remaining records; it's an unusual requiremeent.

Most people would use a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` (which is now the default in the upcoming 2.5 release).